# What causes Django ORM to add duplicate tables?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a Django generic list view.
So it starts by looking at various request paramaters (list filter, sort) and applys the queryset.filter() method a number of times (or none at all) based on the request parameters.

It then does some aggregates, but the totals are coming out incorrectly. Looking at the query, it seems to be adding various tables to the query two or more times.

So a snippet from the FROM part of the query looks as follows:

```
INNER JOIN `sequencing_sample` ON (`sequencing_samplesubprojectstats`.`sample_id` = `sequencing_sample`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_library` ON (`sequencing_sample`.`id` = `sequencing_library`.`sample_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_loadedwith` ON (`sequencing_library`.`id` = `sequencing_loadedwith`.`library_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_passfail` ON (`sequencing_loadedwith`.`passfail_id` = `sequencing_passfail`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_passfail` T6 ON (`sequencing_library`.`passfail_id` = T6.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_organism` ON (`sequencing_sample`.`organism_id` = `sequencing_organism`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_subproject` ON (`sequencing_samplesubprojectstats`.`subproject_id` = `sequencing_subproject`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sequencing_library` T9 ON (`sequencing_sample`.`id` = T9.`sample_id`)
```

The passfail table is a lookup table, and should be duplicated, but the library table is central to the schema, and should not be duplicated as T9

Is there any good documentation on what causes the ORM to add duplicate tables? There are various thing s happening in the view (various filters being optionally applied, annotations on the queryset).

I can use raw SQL, but I would prefer to use Django objects, as sorting and pagination are a lot easier with these.

I would like to know what part of the API is causing the library table to be added a second time so I can potentially avoid it  (if that is possible).